# What is the Max number of days we can have for a sprint

Tags: azure-devops, azure-boards

What is the Max number of days we can have for a sprint in Azure ? From my search i found it to be 30 days, Please correct me if i'm wrong

Comment: 30 days probably comes from SCRUM guidance rather than a coded limitation in the UI of Azure DevOps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why you think it's 30 days. It's not. Sprints lengths are defined by setting a date range for an iteration. You can have any date range you want; I just created one with a range of 75 years.

Comment: For what it's worth, this is something that can trivially be self-answered by simply **trying it out**. You could have had your answer in a few seconds instead of waiting for someone else to answer.

Comment: Actually i do not have access to create a sprint, i'm entering into Devops and preparing for the same.